# How to avoid IE warning for secure content with fancybox version 2?

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I'm using Fancybox version 2.0.6 to load hidden divs into the fancybox, but in IE I get the warning that only secure content will be displayed.  I see there are people who have addressed this issue in version 1.3.4, but version 2 does not have the same code they replaced in the patch (I checked).
Has someone dealt with this already?  Is there another resolution in the latest fancybox version?

Comment: Are you using custom URLs for your images?

Comment: This warning also relates to an external content being accessed and your page is in the local server (intranet) or a non HTTPS content being loaded in a HTTPS address.

Comment: I have seen those warnings when working on local host only and disappear when moving the page to a server, have your tried that?

Comment: @zetlen I'm not using fancybox for images I'm using it for showing a form which is really just a hidden div on the same page.@JFK I didn't even check IE before moving it to the server, it happens in both places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I decided to try installing the older version of fancybox which has a patch for this issue, but before adding the javascript included for the old version I commented out the script lines for the new version and the warning remained!

I then noticed that I had included jquery as instructed  at http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#instructions and didn't change the http to https in this line:

```
<!-- Add jQuery library -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

So the answer is that Fancybox version 2.0.6 does not throw any security warnings in IE, but if you blindly follow the instructions you'll get that warning due to the jquery line. :)

Comment: That's happening because you are using an absolute URI to an unsecure asset. Here's a cheat that works in all browsers, that will access the secure version of Google's jQuery on secure pages: `<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>`